# Extraction layer information inside a polygon from a WMS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, wms, layers

I am wondering how I can exctract data that is inside a polygon that is drawn from a DXF file using QGIS.

Case: I have a boundryline from a polyline in autocad that I export to DXF, and then import it as a Vector-layer. Inside this area I have multiple WMS layers with different information: soiltype, infiltration potential ect.

Is there a way I can export this information to a textfile etc. on what is inside this polygon?

[image: clip from Qgis.]

Comment: You can't. WMS provides not information, but am image of a rendered map/aerial image etc. So it does not contain the data, but represents a visualization of it. To extract actual data, you would need a WFS (vector data) or a WCS (raster data).

Comment: Thanks for replying, i can get this information through a WFS service aswell, how would i go forth gathering that information then? what sort of search should i do in google to point me in  the right direction :) 
I have only basic course in Qgis however there we only went through information allready gathered and saved to direct files we accessed, however i only request a point in the right direction :)

reason i asked orginaly is when i use the identify object command, i do see the information i need in the identifying results, so thought it was possible with the WMS.

Comment: With WMS you can use GetFeatureInfo to get underlying data at a pixel location in the WMS image.  You can read the OGC [WMS](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wms/)/[WFS](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wfs/)/[WCS](https://www.ogc.org/standard/wcs/) API specifications to discover all the details.